# encrypted /tmp doesn't mount at boot time

Tags: cryptsetup

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3, 64-bit. cryptsetup version 1.6.6

Contents of /etc/crypttab (UUIDs replaced to save space):

```
cryptswap1 UUID=XXXX /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
crypttmp1 UUID=YYYY /dev/urandom precheck=/bin/true,tmp=ext3,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

In /etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/crypttmp1 /tmp ext3 defaults,noatime 0 2
```

During boot, encrypted swap is initialized, mounted and used without problems. However, /tmp doesn't, and the following is in dmesg (and /var/log/syslog ):

```
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for crypttmp1...
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd[1]: Starting Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1...
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd-cryptsetup[817]: Encountered unknown /etc/crypttab option 'precheck=/bin/true', ignoring.
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd-cryptsetup[817]: Encountered unknown /etc/crypttab option 'tmp=ext3', ignoring.
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd-cryptsetup[818]: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 256 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXX.
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd-cryptsetup[817]: crypt_load() failed on device /dev/disk/by-uuid/YYYY.
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd-cryptsetup[817]: Failed to activate: Invalid argument
Sep 19 11:15:51 computer systemd[1]: systemd-cryptsetup@crypttmp1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Further details:

- removing 'tmp=ext3' or using explicit ext4 didn't help
- removing 'precheck=/bin/true' didn't help
- if I remove/comment out corresponding line from /etc/fstab and, after booting OS and logging in use commands

  sudo cryptdisks_start crypttmp1
  sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/mapper/crypttmp1 /tmp

then encrypted /tmp  is created and normally mounted.

I would appreciate hints to what prevents the above partition to normally mount during boot.